# I got some trouble when I'm running the code

Tags: python

n= 3n+1

Hi.
I made this code.
I operate it then I got some error message.
How can I solve it?
Below is the error code.

3n+1
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're missing the * sign for multiplication. There is no implicit multiplication in python.

Comment: OK. `n=3n + 1` is invalid syntax, and that's exactly what the message tells you. What would you like us to add?

Comment: It looks like you're learning a programming language for the first time. May I suggest a thorough tutorial?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
n= 3*n+1         # asterisk (*) for multiplication
```

instead of your

```
n= 3n+1          # 3n begins with a digit so Python expect a number - but n is not allowed
```